# Microtype is not working with lualatex on MikTex

Tags: luatex, miktex, microtype, miktex2.9

When I compile a document on a certain MikTeX installation on Windows with `microtype` 2.7 (determined in MikTeX Package Manager) using `lualatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "mwe".tex` I get the following warning:

```
    Package microtype Warning: You don't seem to be using either pdftex, luatex, or
xetex.
(microtype) `microtype' only works with these engines.
(microtype) I will quit now..
```

Compiling the same document with TeXLive, `microtype` 2.7 and `lualatex` does not give me a warning.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{microtype}
\listfiles
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

`pdflatex` and `xelatex` seem to work in MikTeX. What might cause this problem and how can I fix it?

**Edit:**

Here is a list of the used files:

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
blindtext.sty    2012/01/06 V2.0 blindtext-Package
  xspace.sty    2014/10/28 v1.13 Space after command names (DPC,MH)
microtype.sty    2013/05/23 v2.5a Micro-typographical refinements (RS)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
 ***********
```

Comment: can you show the log, in particular exact luatex and microtype versions?

Comment: The version in the file list is somehow older than in the Package Manager. After an update in the Admin and user Package Manager everything works fine.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved by an update.

Answer (score 2):

Too long for an comment.

With an current version of MiKTeX I can compile your code without error or warning. The used packages and versions are:

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
blindtext.sty    2012/01/06 V2.0 blindtext-Package
  xspace.sty    2014/10/28 v1.13 Space after command names (DPC,MH)
microtype.sty    2017/07/07 v2.7 Micro-typographical refinements (RS)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
microtype-luatex.def    2017/07/07 v2.7 Definitions specific to luatex (RS)
microtype.cfg    2017/07/07 v2.7 microtype main configuration file (RS)
mt-LatinModernRoman.cfg    2013/03/13 v1.0 microtype config. file: Latin Modern 
Roman (RS)
 ***********
```